# Filter objects in ManyToMany relationship by multiple criteria

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I want to get the model instance of my 'Collection' object where 'request.user' is either in 'owner' or 'contributors' relationship and id of that object is 'collection_id'. Here is my code:

models.py

```
    class Collection(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        contributors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='contributors', blank=True)
```

views.py

```
    def collection_edit(request, collection_id)
        ...
        # Here I want to check if request.user is in contributors or owner
        collection = Collection.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user, pk=collection_id).first()
        # Do stuff
        ...
```

Also is 'on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING' in owner relationship going to break my database integrity if user is deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Collection.objects.filter(Q(owner=request.user) | Q(contributors=request.user))
```

Here we thus retrieve `Collection` objects, for which the `owner` is `request.user`, *or* `request.user` is one of the contributors. If he is both the owner and a contributor, it will also be part of the collection.

> Also is `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` in owner relationship going to break my database integrity if user is deleted?

Yes, since that means that the `user_id` field at that moment will contain a value of a primary key of a user that no longer exists. Most databases will however *not* allow that, and raise an `IntegrityError`. It might be better to use [**`PROTECT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) if you do not want let Django remove a `User` if there is a still a `Collection` with `user` as `owner`.

Comment: Thank you! I added pk=collection_id to each Q and I got what I needed. Is it maybe more efficient if I got the object via pk first and the checked for relations once it is fetched from db?

Comment: @mmdfan: no, since the relations are checked with a `JOIN` at the database. So this will be done in *one* query, instead of multiple ones if you check the relations yourself.